# python selenium web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am a total newbie with python but whenever I run this code I get the following error "Message: Unable to locate element: (//div[@class = 'contact-us'])" Even though when I inspect the site I can see the div.
Here is my code:

```
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://einstein.exchange/contact-us')
BTC = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class = 'contact-us'])")
BTC_html = BTC.get_attribute('innerHTML')
print (BTC_html)
driver.close()
with open("OutputEinstein.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(format(BTC_html), file=text_file)
```

i have run similar codes for two other sites and they worked fine. So I am not sure why for this site it is not working.

Comment: try adding wait ->  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class = 'contact-us'])"))
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to access this page, I was presented with a Google Captcha verification. Does this happen to you as well? If not, the following code must suffice:

```
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://einstein.exchange/contact-us')

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """(//div[@class = 'contact-us'])""")))

BTC = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class = 'contact-us'])")
BTC_html = BTC.get_attribute('innerHTML')
print (BTC_html)
driver.close()
with open("OutputEinstein.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(format(BTC_html), file=text_file)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: No i dont get the google captcha verification.I get the follwoing error "return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25b2' in position 556: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: Ok I got it running I just chose a class with a smaller selection instead of the whole page. Thanks guys.